# Conexão com Git no servidor Jenkins na Azure: Host key verification failed

Tags: git, jenkins

No repositório na URL:

```
git@xxxxx:root/ghnetsoft-utilitario.git
```

Deu este erro:

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h git@ xxxxxx :root/ghnetsoft-utilitario.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout:
stderr: Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Conexão com sucesso

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

No seu cenário você tem o Jenkins tentando fazer um `git-ls` em algum servidor Git (que você colocou `xxxxxx` para esconder qual na sua pergunta).

Provavelmente este erro:

```
stderr: Host key verification failed.
```

É [porque](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15174194/jenkins-host-key-verification-failed) "debaixo dos panos" o git está dando um erro pedindo confirmação se o seu repositório `xxxxxx` é um servidor conhecido. Para exemplo, vamos imaginar que o `xxxxxx` é o GitHub.

Se você entrar com o usuário Jenkins e executar diretamente o seguinte comando (trocando o `xxxxxx` pelo seu servidor git, obviamente):

```
git ls-remote -h git@github.com:root/ghnetsoft-utilitario.git HEAD
```

Ele deve gerar um aviso parecido com este:

```
The authenticity of host 'xxxxxxx (127.0.0.1)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 97:8c:1b:f2:6f:14:6b:5c:3b:ec:aa:46:46:74:7c:40.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

Escolhendo `yes` deve resolver, pois daí ele vai adicionar o `github.com` ao arquivo `~/.ssh/known_hosts`.

Outra alternativa é você [usar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13363553/git-error-host-key-verification-failed-when-connecting-to-remote-repository) este comando para atingir o mesmo objetivo:

```
ssh-keyscan -t rsa github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```